# Visual Studio Code error. startup error message

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a startup error message in Visual Studio Code:

[image]

How can I fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you change anything in the extensions folder? May be you broke some files there. If yes then rollback your changes. If no then reinstall VSCode.

Comment: This looks like a broken install. Can you uninstall VS Code and make sure the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code is deleted and then reinstall.

Comment: No. I just installed Atom and I have the same bug. If I am not mistaken VSCode is based on Atom... Perhaps the problem in it.
I have reinstalled os and this issue disappeared.
I did not understand what it was:(